# SQL : How to add a dummy column (with each cell containing "A", or an integer or some other string

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table on sql which is to an excel file. It provides the source data. Just to make pivot tables etc easier, I want to add an additional column, a dummy one, which contains 'A' in every cell. or it could be an integer or another random string. It's not important what's contained in these, i just need them to be there and for it to be uniform.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance. BTW, I'm using the sql server on Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 3):

```
select

*,

'A' as dummy_value

from [Table]
```